# Regular Conditional Bayesian Experiment

Tags: statistics, bayesian

In "Elements of Bayesian Statistics" (1990), Florens, Mouchart and Rolin describe two basic forms of reduction of a Bayesian experiment: Marginalization and Conditioning (Ch. 1). I don't understand the conditioning reduction and would appreciate an explanation, if possible in measure-theoretic terms. Thanks.

EDIT: I failed to mention that what i'm struggling with is the definition of a *regular* conditional experiment.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59661/regular-conditional-bayesian-experiment) one from [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), and has been answered there.